# Conditional Formatting with greater than & less than parameters based on date in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

Trying to conditionally format a cell based on the date in the cell.  My ultimate goal is to try and track warranty expiration dates on some of the product we maintain. Within 30 days of expiration date listed in the cell I would like the cell to simply highlight yellow. If cell A1 date is today() or greater have it highlight red. For the red formatting I have a conditional formatting formula as: ="A1>=today()". This works great.  I tried to setup another rule of "Cell value between A1 and A1-30" and that only half works.  It highlights everything older then today, not just the last 30 days.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Can you please show us the exact formulas you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the formulas as following?

Yellow：

=And(Today()<K19,K19<Today()+30)

Red：

=Today()>=K19

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is the cleanest way, but here is something that works.
The rules have to be in this order to correctly override each other and highlight the cell accordingly.

*RED -  Cell Value > today()*

*YELLOW - Formula:  =today()-K19<=30*
**K19 is the cell with the data

*NO FORMAT - Cell Value < today()-31*

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0cDU.jpg)

Comment: There's a guide in the Help section for merging duplicate accounts. Also, if you were trying to add info to your question, just use the EDIT button. This isn't a forum. Making your question better and more complete is a good thing. But also, answering your own question is good too: just know those are two different things.

Comment: Sorry, first question on this site.  I'll work on the merging and thanks for the info